# process.env.NODE_ENV variables into scss via rollup

Tags: sass, rollup, rollupjs, postcss, sass-loader

Is there a way to reference a process.env.NODE_ENV in a scss file by passing it to the sass-loader in postcss for rollup. If so anyone know how to go about this?

UPDATE1
Ok, so this is my rollup.config.js. I'm getting a weird issue where sometimes the $env is undefined and sometimes it is set to the right process.env.NODE_ENV

```
import serve from "rollup-plugin-serve";
import livereload from "rollup-plugin-livereload";
import babel from '@rollup/plugin-babel';
import { nodeResolve } from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import replace from '@rollup/plugin-replace';
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss';
import { uglify } from 'rollup-plugin-uglify';



const build = process.env.BUILD ? process.env.BUILD : 'development';

export default {
  input: "src/index.js",
  output: {
    file: "dist/bundle.js",
    sourcemap: true,
    compact: true
  },
  plugins: [
    postcss({
      use: {
        sass: {
          data: "$env: " + process.env.NODE_ENV + ";"
        }
      },
    }),
    nodeResolve({
      extensions: [".js"],
    }),
    replace({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(build)
    }),
    babel({
      presets: ["@babel/preset-react"],
    }),
    commonjs(),
    build === 'production' && uglify(),
    serve({
      verbose: true,
      contentBase: ["", "public"],
      host: "localhost",
      port: 3000,
    }),
    build === 'development' &&
    livereload({ watch: "dist" }),
  ]
};
```